# Question on expected waiting time calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

A sequence of random variables, (not necessarily independent) are generated as follows. At each time $i \in [n]$, we toss a coin with head probability $\delta_i$ (these are random variables themselves). If the coin lands a head, we pay a cost $h_i$ and otherwise we pay a cost $t$. What is the expected cost paid before one of the coins lands tails? Specifically, how to deal with the fact that we stop after a tail lands?

Here is what I have tried, let $X_i$ be a r.v. which denotes the total cost paid till the $i^{th}$ iteration. Then,
$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}+\delta_i]\delta_i+\mathbb{E}[X_{i-1}+t](1-\delta_i).$

However I am not sure how to use this fact. Can someone point me to some relevant literature for this problem?

Comment: I'm confused about the phrase "not necessarily independent", given that you do indeed know that the $i^{th}$ flip has probability $\delta_i$ of heads. So are you saying that somehow $\delta_i$ is not fixed...i.e. it could depend on whether or not the first flip is heads? That would make $\delta_i$ random.

Comment: @T_M, Yes my bad in phrasing the question. $\delta_i$'s are indeed random and not fixed at the beginning of the experiment. However $\delta_1$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence, as otherwise it is unlikely the problem is tractable. Let $X_n=1$ if the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ flip is heads and be zero otherwise. $X_n$ has a Poisson binomial distribution. Set $\tau = \inf\{n>0: X_n=0\}$. Then for each positive integer $n$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\tau = n) &= \mathbb P(X_1=X_2=\cdots=X_{n-1}=1,X_n=0\}\\
&=  \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathbb P(X_i=1) \mathbb P(X_n=0)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \delta_n (1-\delta_n).
\end{align}
Let $C_n$ denote the cost paid on the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ flip. Since $\tau$ is a stopping time, it follows from Wald's identity that the expected cost paid before flipping a tails is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau-1} h_iX_i\right] &= \sum_{i=1}^{\tau-1}h_i\delta_i(1-\delta_n).
\end{align}
We cannot say much more without further assumptions on the $h_i$ and $d_i$.